# symfony - find which guard authenticator is used

Tags: php, symfony, security

my security.yml looks like this

```
security:
encoders:
    AppBundle\Entity\User: bcrypt
    AppBundle\Entity\Agency: bcrypt
providers:
    chain_provider:
            chain:
                providers: [agency_db, user_db]
    user_db:
        entity: { class: AppBundle:User, property: email }
    agency_db:
        entity: { class: AppBundle:Agency, property: email }
```

LE:

```
firewalls:
    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        anonymous: ~
        guard:
            authenticators:
            - app.form_login_authenticator
            - app.agency_form_login_athenticator
            entry_point: AppBundle\Security\FormLoginAuthenticator
        logout:
          path: /logout
          target: /
    agency:
        pattern: ^/agency/
        guard:
            authenticators:
            - AppBundle\Security\AgencyFormLoginAuthenticator
        logout:
          path: /logout_agency
          target: /
access_control:
          - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
          - { path: ^/agency, roles: ROLE_AGENCY }
          - { path: ^/, roles: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ROLE_USER] }
```

i need to figure out which provider was used, so when i get the email from token storage

```
$a = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
```

i need to know where to get his data from - which Entity i should query

Comment: Please Verify the `firewalls:`  section in that u can figure it out which provider is used.

Comment: and how would i query that in a Controller ?

Comment: Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29823352/find-user-by-username-from-multiple-providers-symfony2)